# Xor tuple function

Tags: python, procedure

I'm a beginner in python and I'm blocked on a series of instructions I have to do. I need to make a function that takes into parameter two tuples of 3 integers. The function will perform a xor between the 2 first integers, then the 2 second integers, and the 2 third integers. Finally, it will return these results as a tuple.

Here's the function I used earlier in the code:

```
def xor (a,b):
    return (bool (a) and not(bool(b))) or (not(bool (a))) and bool (b)
```

If it's not accurate or downright false, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem you're having? What inputs produce what wrong results?

Comment: I believe you can check... if it is giving right values or not.

Comment: Bitwise XOR or boolean XOR ?

Comment: boolean XOR, when i checked the code with xor values were correct for 0,0 and 1,1 but not for 1,0 and 0,1
the problem is i dont know how to write the function i tried declaring tuples in parameters and then calling the xor (or boolean xor) for each couple of integers but it didnt work

Answer (score 5):

In Python, the `^` infix operator represents xor for integers (you can see this by looking at the documentation for `int.__xor__` but *be careful*, the `__xor__` behavior can be overloaded for other types and may not reflect anything related to a usual logical xor operation).

So in this case, you can do it like:

```
def xor(tup_a, tup_b):
   return tuple(a^b for a,b in zip(tup_a, tup_b))
```

For example:

```
In [5]: xor((1,2,3), (3, 2, 1))
Out[5]: (2, 0, 2)
```

This makes use of the `zip` function, which you should read about if not familiar. One convention about this function: if `tup_a` and `tup_b` do not have the same lengths, then the zipping process will only happen up to the length of the shorter one, and the rest of the items from the longer one will be discarded.

If you want to write some extra code to do something special to handle those extra items, you'll have to modify this function definition to use `itertools.izip_longest`.

For example, suppose that if `tup_a` is shorter than `tup_b` then you want to use a dummy value of `0` in the places where `tup_a` isn't long enough to match up with something from `tup_b` ...

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def xor(tup_a, tup_b, fill=0):
    return tuple(a^b for a,b in izip_longest(tup_a, tup_b, fillvalue=fill))
```

Then:

```
In [11]: xor((1,2,3), (3, 2, 1))
Out[11]: (2, 0, 2)

In [12]: xor((1,2), (3, 2, 1))
Out[12]: (2, 0, 1)
```

Comment: i was just looking for the role of the .zip function, appreciate that.

Comment: i'm working with 2 tuples of the same size so i dont need it but i'll probabely need it later, so the zip function cuts the items of the longer tuple and if we want to do modifications to those discarded items we'll use the itertools.izip_longest (like fill empty itemps in a with zeroes)

Comment: so, what's the the syntax to execute this function i'm trying but i obviously missing something;

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `a` and `b` are integer tuples of same size (you need to assert that):

```
def xor(a, b):
    return tuple(a[i]^v for i, v in enumerate(b))
```

Comment: This returns a generator. You have to return `tuple(a[i]^v for i, v in enumerate(b))`